Transfer Speed Between Drives Connected To Wifi Hub Via Docking Station Is Extremely Slow
I have connected and mapped two HDDs to my Laptop over my home network connection. The HDDs are connected to a Docking Station and the docking station in the connected to the hub. When transferring data between the two drives by simply dragging and dropping between the two drives in file explorer, it is incredibly slow at around 1-3MB/s. I am assuming this is because it transferring the data from one HDD to my over Wifi laptop and then back to the other HDD over Wifi again which is understandably slow. Is there a way to bypass my laptop and transfer directly between the two drives over the network or not? My set up is as follows:

BT Smart Hub 3
Universal Docking Station Kensington SD3600
Western Digital WD Blue WD10SPZX 1TB


If your WiFi router has some sort of terminal interface, ssh for instance, you could run it from there, but even then the data would be going from the drive, over the USB dock cable to the router, then back out that same USB dock cable to the other drive. You have two choke points in your setup, and this WILL cause a lot of slowness. For larger transfers, connecting one drive directly to the router (no docking station) and the other to your computer will the simplest way to get decent speeds. Though, connecting both to USB ports on different hubs in your computer would be faster still.

@music2myear So if I were to attach the docking station to a Raspberry Pi and then connect that to the router, could I transfer files between my HDD's connected to the docking station from my Laptop without it having to transfer the files to my Laptop, therefore bypassing the router and speeding up the transfer?

Right now your files are traveling in a long "U" shape, going from Drive1, Pi, Router, Laptop, Router, Pi, Drive2. Each step on that path is busy processing data going two direction, each link is handling the data twice. ANY rearrangement that straightens that path out, turning the "U" into an "I" will produce a marked improvement, and the fewer steps on that straight path the better too. But, you didn't mention a Pi in your question. Connect the drives there, access the Pi, and run the transfer directly.

Please consider editing your question to add further details, like your Pi.

@music2myear I don't have a Raspberry Pi, I was just wondering if it would work as an inexpensive solution

Got it. That makes sense.

@music2myear Should I add it anyway as part of my question?

The main problem you have is that with your current setup data traveling between the two drives is actually traveling from Drive 1, over USB1 to the hub, to the router, over the network to the computer, and then back over the network to the router, to the hub, over USB 2 to Drive 2. This of this as a "U" or "Y" shaped route.
This means that the hub, the link between the hub and the router, and the network all have to handle, process, and transfer the data with each of their own limited set of resources. Each link and each double-used resource impacts your transfer speeds.
In order to get the best speed out of a give set of systems you have two goals:

Straighten the process out, turning the "U" or the "Y" into an "I".
Remove every step that you can.

First, just connecting a drive at each end of the line (your computer and the hub) will speed things up a lot as you will have a straight line path and no system in the link will have to be passing data both directions of the transfer.
Second, getting rid of any of the steps you can get rid of will also help. If the drives can connect directly to the router instead of through the hub, that'll help. If the router has SSH access, you might be able to use this to run the transfer, removing the computer and the network links between the router and the computer from the equation.
You can add equipment that will simplify things, like a Pi or other NUC device the drives connect to, which will allow you to remove the router, your computer, and all the links between them from the equation.
Also, depending on what sort of data you're transferring, and what it looks like now vs what it'll look like going forward, you may use a more aggressive process such as connecting both drives to your computer to complete the initial "seed" transfer, and then handle the ongoing future transfers, which might be smaller or incremental, over the slower network setup.
So, think through the entire solution, what you need today and what this will look like going forward, apply the 2 principles of straightening out the paths and simplifying the system, and you'll be able to put together a solution that improves your speed today and works well going forward.
